# Reading data from a .txt file into 2d array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
double data[50][6];

ifstream fin;
fin.open("Scores.txt");

if (!fin)
    cout << "File does not exist";

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; i++) {
        fin >> data[i][j];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a simple array that reads data from a text file. The .txt file has 6 columns of data with 50 entries in each column. Whenever i run the program (using visual studio 2015), i get an error message. "program.exe" has stopped working...windows is looking for a solution to this problem". I'm new to c++ arrays but I've researched them extensively and cant see anything wrong with this code. Help?

Comment: Your second `for` is broken, should be `j++` instead of `i++`

Comment: aha! I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you guys saved my day, thanks a lot, I had same problem.